# XSLT sort using letters and numbers

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for assistance with addressing an issue I'm encountering with a XSLT stylesheet I'm applying to a basic XML file, which will output basic HTML for a table I'm building. Specifically, I am trying to apply a `<xslt:sort select="" />` to the content I'm outputting based on a ID element, which includes text (Always starts with the letter 'A') and single and double digit numbers. However, when I run the script, it does not handle double digit numbers well. It places A10 after A1, when I want A10 to appear after A9.

Example XML source file:

```
<categories name="Category name goes here" version="2020">
        <category name="A1">
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH1"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH2"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH3"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH4"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH5"/>
        </category>
        <category name="A2">
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH1"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH2"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH3"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH4"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH5"/>
        </category>
        <category name="A9">
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH1"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH2"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH3"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH4"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH5"/>
        </category>
        <category name="A10">
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH1"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH2"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH3"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH4"/>
            <error id="ABC.DEFGH5"/>
        </category>
```

Here is what my XSLT sort currently looks like:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-before(@name, ' '), 'A')" data-type="number"/>
```

What do I need to add here for it to consider double digit numbers properly? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the sort as follows.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/categories">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="category">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@name, 'A')" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track, but the `substring-before` is serving no purpose and messing things up. Try just removing that:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(@name, 'A')" data-type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which XSLT version you are using. (Please ALWAYS specify this when asking about XSLT on StackOverflow. We need to know because many people are still using ancient versions of the language).

XSLT 2.0 introduced the ability to name a collation on xsl:sort, and XSLT 3.0 introduced some standard URIs for particular collations. With XSLT 2.0 your processor vendor may supply a collation with the required properties; with XSLT 3.0 you can request use of the Unicode Collation Algorithm with the property `numeric=yes` which gives the order you are after:

```
<xsl:sort select="..." 
          collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes"/>
```

Numeric=yes is defined so that any sequence of digits in the strings to be sorted is treated as a number rather than as a sequence of characters.

Comment: Good point, Michael. An omission on my part. I am using XSLT 2.0, so thanks for the added substance. I will take that into account for future reference!